# Specifying directory path for data base connectivity

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Dynamic web project ,in that i am creating config.properites file for Data base connectivity.

```
SampleProject 
  ->WebContent
    ->WEB_INF
       ->config.properties
       ->Index.jsp
```

i am reading Connectivity Details from configuration file in Index.jsp as follows

```
           Properties props = new Properties();        
          FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("WEB-INF/config.properties");
            props.load(in);
            in.close();
            String driver = props.getProperty("driver");              
            String url = props.getProperty("url");
            String username = props.getProperty("username");
            String password = props.getProperty("password");                 
            class.forName(driver);
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

but it's throwing

```
   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Index.jsp at line 66

    63:             
    64:            
    65:             FileInputStream in1 = 
    66:                     new FileInputStream("WEB-INF/config.properties");
    67:             props.load(in1);
    68:             in.close();
    69:        
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:553)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:447)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause    
java.io.FileNotFoundException: WEB-INF/config.properties (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)

exception.. can anyone help me how to give the directory path?
```

Comment: you should try this:`project->webcontent->web_inf->index.jsp`

Comment: will you pls paste full stacktrace

Comment: wrong way to access the properties

Comment: WEB-INF is a secured folder and it can not be accessed like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a very good idea to put configuration files in the web content directoy, which might make it accessible from the outside. I would rather put the config file somewhere in the classpath and use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource('config.properties')` to get an `InputStream` and load the property file.

Edit: Question has been edited. Having config under `WEB-INF` is better. Then you can use the methods of `ServletContext` to load the resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to store your properties in WEB-INF, you can try to resolve the file system path where it is deployed to using [`ServletContext.getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).

However, I'd also recommend moving the file to the classpath and load it as a resource, as NilsH suggests in his answer. Once you do that, you can also make use of [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) to read the properties.